# SSRS export freezes with conditional formatting

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I created an SSRS report in SSRS 2016 that runs and exports to Excel in about 2 seconds.  When I add conditional formatting the report still runs in about 2 seconds, but the export to Excel hangs.  I've let it run as long as 10 minutes before cancelling.  The report only has 600 records.

I've tried both the following to no avail:

```
    =IIF(Fields!StatusTypeName.Value = "H5-Active", "Green", "Blue")

    =Switch(Fields!StatusTypeName.Value = "H5-Active", "Green"
     Switch(Fields!StatusTypeName.Value ="H4", "Blue")
```

I've put the expressions in the BackgroundColor under Properties.

I don't understand why such a simple thing would cause this to not work.  Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: To be sure you haven't introduced some other simultaneous change, have you tried taking out the conditional formatting expression, keeping everything else the same, and testing the Excel export?

Comment: Yes, it exports perfectly without the formatting.  The report only has 600 rows but it has about 55 columns.  When I ran the report with a filter to only return about 5 columns it exported with the formatting with no problems.  So it seems to be an issue with the number of columns, though I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have the correct switch statement. Switch should appear only once and the corresponding conditions inside brackets.

This is how it should be

```
 =Switch(Fields!StatusTypeName.Value = "H5-Active", "Green",
           Fields!StatusTypeName.Value ="H4", "Blue")
```

Comment: It still freezes.  But still, my original way ran in a couple of seconds.  It's only the export to Excel that freezes.